# How to overload stream in struct

Tags: c++

I've a namespace that needs to overload ostream for compiling, when I added in the struct, it complain about two parameters, only one allowed, when I added after the struct, still not compiling:

```
namespace ORT {

struct MimeType {
     MimeType(const std::string & type = "")
    : type(type)
    {
    }
    std::string toString() const { return std::string(type); }
    std::string type;        
};    
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const MimeType& mt) {
   std::cout << mt.type;
return stream;
}
...
```

it says:  In function `ORT::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, ORT::MimeType const&)':
/ort.h:56: multiple definition of`ORT::operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&, ORT::MimeType const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/x86_64/bin/libopenrtb.3da2981d03414ced8d640e67111278c1.so] Error 1

But I only include ostream, no multiple instance.
When I only put:

It says:
error: expected initializer before âstructâ
error: expected â}â at end of input
make: *** Error 1

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're defining a function in your header file which is not marked `inline`.  Either move the definition of `operator <<` to the corresponding .cpp file, or add the `inline` keyword:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< // ...
```

Personally I'd move it to the .cpp file.  Then you can move the `#include <iostream>` in your header to the .cpp file as well, and add `#include <iosfwd>` to your header, which is a slimmer dependency.